# Query records from a table with criteria based on another table

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to query records from a table with criteria based on another table? I'm not very good at MySQL JOIN so can some one point me to the right direction? here's the case:

Table 1: tbl_users(id,username,points)
Table 2: tbl_items(id,user_id,title,cost)

I want to query all items for all user_ids but only if their cost is less than the number of points that this user_id has. I know I can go on it one by one in a loop but I'm looking for the smarter way.

Thank You,

Comment: what have you tried so far to get this working?  Joins are useful for this, but we're here to help, not to just do the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the two tables based on the user id and in where add your condition need to be checked.

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_users` AS `user` 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_items` AS `item` ON (`user`.`id` = `item`.`user_id`) 
WHERE `item`.`cost` < `user`.`points`
```

Comment: Why a left join? he asked for "all the items..." and the where clause should go inside the ON aswell

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT `*` FROM `tbl_users` JOIN `tbl_items` ON (`tbl_users`.`id`= `tbl_items`.`user_id` and `tbl_items`.`cost`<`tbl_users`.`points`)
```

Comment: You should explain your answer. Assume the asker knows nothing about SQL. What is your code doing?

Comment: This select  everything from tbl_users and join the table tbl_items but only where the user_id from tbl_items is the same with the id from tbl_users and the cost is less than points. If the id from tbl_users doesn't exists in tbls_items that user id will not be selected. The array contains all name fields from both tables.

Answer (score -1):

```
select a.* from tbl_users as a join tbl_items as b on a.id=b.id where a.points>b.cost;
```